# Auto select lookup tables based on input parameter

Tags: c, macros

I am a C newbie, I have stored few look up Tables in the header file that need to be used in my C program.
For example, I'm using

```
static int LookupTable[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] = FIRST_TABLE;
static int LookupTable[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] = SECOND_TABLE;
static int LookupTable[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] = THIRD_TABLE;
static int LookupTable[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] = FOURTH_TABLE;
```

I have defined macros for ROW_SIZE and COL_SIZE where the COL_SIZE is fixed and ROW_SIZE is variable.

```
#define COL_SIZE    2     
#define ROW_SIZE    2       //<! 1 x input (where input = {2,3,4,5})
```

I need to use the lookup tables based on the input value. That is, use:

- FIRST_TABLE when input is 2 (so ROW_SIZE = 1 x 2 )
- SECOND_TABLE when input is 3 (so ROW_SIZE = 1 x 3)
- THIRD_TABLE when input is 4 (so ROW_SIZE = 1 x 4)
- FOURTH_TABLE when input is 5 (so ROW_SIZE = 1 x 5)

Currently, I'm manually updating the ROW_SIZE everytime based on the input value and using the respective lookuptable as shown below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define FIRST_TABLE \
{ \
{1,2},\
{3,4}\
}

#define SECOND_TABLE \
{ \
{1,2},\
{11,22},\
{3,4}\
}

#define THIRD_TABLE \
{ \
{1,2},\
{11,22},\
{21,31},\
{3,4}\
}

#define FOURTH_TABLE \
{ \
{1,2},\
{10,20},\
{30,40},\
{50,60},\
{3,4}\
}


#define ROW_SIZE    2       // 2->FIRST_TABLE, 3->SECOND_TABLE, 4-> THIRD_TABLE, 5->FOURTH_TABLE
#define COL_SIZE    2
int main()
{

    static int LookupTable[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] = FIRST_TABLE;
    //static int LookupTable[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] = SECOND_TABLE;
    //static int LookupTable[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] = THIRD_TABLE;
    //static int LookupTable[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE] = FOURTH_TABLE;

    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<ROW_SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<COL_SIZE;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",LookupTable[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please advise me on how I could define the ROW_SIZE and select the lookuptable automatically when the input value is known. For example, if input = 2, it should automatically choose ROW_SIZE = 2 and select FIRST_TABLE.
*Please note that 'input' value is an external parameter coming from different source file.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is `sint32` defined on your system?

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, it helps to see what you are attempting.  I did run your code, and for each static run (i.e. with only one definition of `LookupTable` uncommented, it works.  As written, `LookupTable` is being treated as a static 2D array.  It is fully defined at compile time.  If attempting to define it at runtime, it will be treated as a variable length array, so it cannot be defined using `static` storage duration, nor can it be initialized....

Comment: ... for this reason, using a macro with an argument, which is useful in many cases, is not going to help here, i.e. to be used as a _variable_ value in the first index of `LookupTable[ROW_SIZE(i)][COL_SIZE]`.  How flexible are you toward looking at alternative methods?

Comment: @ryyker any alternate method will do as I couldn't find anything useful till now.

Comment: See ***Edit*** _to address request in comments:_ in my post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, both of your macros are only definable before run-time.  i.e. at compile-time, the value that defines your macro is locked in.

For your macro to produce a *variable* value, change:

```
#define ROW_SIZE    250     //<! 25 x parameter (where parameter = {10,15,20,25,...,100})
```

To:

```
#define ROW_SIZE(x)    25*(x)     //<! 25 x parameter (where parameter = {10,15,20,25,...,100})
```

Then in the calling code, `x` should be defined in scope of where the macro is called.  In this example, `x` is created as an `int [4]` array with automatic scope. It could be a global, or passed as a function argument, as long as it is defined:

```
int i, x[4]={10,15,20,25};
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    //select and use lookup
    LookupTable[ROW_SIZE(x[i])][COL_SIZE];// Each iteration is expanded to
                                          // LookupTable[25*x[i]][COL_SIZE];

    ...
```

For more information, here is a *[C macros tutorial](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html)*.

***Edit*** to address request in comments:

> A lookup table is simply an initialized array that contains
>   precalculated information. They are typically used to avoid performing
>   complex (and hence time consuming) calculations.
>   ...and more on tables *[From A tutorial on lookup tables in C](https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2010/01/a-tutorial-on-lookup-tables-in-c/)*.

With that in mind, there is too much I do not know about how *you* intend to use your lookup tables, but given the description of your needs, which includes tables of differing sizes, and the need to access them dynamically, the following illustrates one method where instead of #defines, the collection of tables is created using arrays of `static const int`, (varying sizes) and a pointer to an array: `int *[]`, where size == *count of tables in collection*, can be accessed simply by by normal array indexing.

The following is implemented as described above, and demonstrates a method that can be used to *Auto select lookup tables based on input parameter.*

```
// define in header file 

//replaces your #define tables
static const int table1[1][2] = {1,2};
static const int table2[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
static const int table3[3][2] = {{1,2},{11,22},{3,4}};
static const int table4[4][2] = {{1,2},{11,22},{21,31},{3,4}};
static const int table5[5][2] = {{1,2},{10,20},{30,40},{50,60},{3,4}};

#define MAX_TABLES 5

//array of pointers to allow lookup table selection via array indexing.
//( static scope necessary if table is used in more than one .c file )
static int *table[MAX_TABLES] = {(int *)table1, (int *)table2, (int *)table3, (int *)table4, (int *)table5};


// end - define in header file

void access_table(int table);

int main(void)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<MAX_TABLES;i++)
    {
        access_table(i);//select lookup tables based on input parameter ( i )   
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;

}

void access_table(int index) // view contents of the selected table
{
    //by definition all tables have rows  equal to table number and columns always == 2
    int loops = 2*index+2;
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<loops;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", table[index][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Produces the following output:
[image]

Comment: Down voter, if is there something I can do to address the problem please point it out.

Comment: x value in my program is coming from another source file and if I try to implement this, I'm getting an error message **'storage size of LookupTable isn't constant'**

Comment: @Shannon - Can you please edit your post to include a [mcve], showing examples of the relevant sections of your code, and include the exact wording of any error messages, and where they occur in the code examples.  I am being pulled away from my desk frequently this morning, but will respond as I am able to.

Comment: I have edited the question as requested and added a working example code.